# How to embed video in iframe

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

Using HTML5 Video Support is pretty amazing but doesn't work in IE versions, So i didn't prefer it.

I am using MVC4 Razor View engine for development.

I came up with this issue-

While i embed video directly from youtube then it is working fine. But when i upload a video and then show it through `@Model.FilePath` then it is not even showing iframe there. The path is correct.

**Controller-**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, SystemUser user)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Logo/");
                file.SaveAs(path + file.FileName);

                string filePath = "/Logo/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                string Extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                var scope = (from u in dv.SystemUsers
                             where u.UserId == this.LoggedInUser.UserId
                             select u).FirstOrDefault();
                scope.FilePath = filePath;
                scope.FileName = file.FileName;
                dv.SystemUsers.GetModifiedMembers(scope);
                dv.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("userprofile", "User");

            }
           return View();
        }
```

**View-**

```
@model MvcApplication8.Models.SystemUser
<h2>
    UserProfile</h2>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="@Model.FilePath" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

**FilePath-**

```
/Logo/video-2012-12-08-21-31-56.mp4
```

While working with images instead of video using `<img src="@Model.FilePath">` it was working excellent.

What went wrong with iframe embedding?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for network (with example devTool F12 Chrome) if he found your url ? After saved your video, can you read it ?

you can try with

```
    @Url.Content("~/Logo/video-2012-12-08-21-31-56.mp4")
```

OR

UPDATE

you do this :

```
             @Url.Content(Model.Filepath)
```

This work fine for me !

or example (jsfiddle) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yyvdc/)

Comment: Thanks for working on this, But it is not about just a static video path. I am saving path and then showing it through `@Model.Filepath`

Comment: Still struggling with it, I get the FilePath but it is welcoming me with `Unable to resolve the server's DNS address` error.